# How can I stop command injection when using shell_exec in php7?

Tags: php, security

I have an html form that asks the user to input a domain name, this is posted to the php7.0 page below for processing by a shell script which then passes output through aha for writing to an html page which is then displayed.

The problem I have is how can I prevent users from injecting commands like:

**domain.com | rm * -rf**

I thought this could be done using safe_mode and restricting the directory from which commands can be run but it seems this feature is now deprecated.

```
$domain_arg = escapeshellarg( $_POST['domain'] );
$today = date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");
$cmd = "/home/ubuntu/dtest/dtest.sh $domain_arg | aha -b -t 'Domain test of $domain_arg' > /var/www/website/results/$domain_arg.$today.html";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
header("Location: http://the.web.com/results/$result.$today.html");
```

Comment: Pretty dangerous to allow user input to be injected into a `exec` command. You better have some really really good validation before you do this. I'm sure you can write a validator that makes sure that the input is a valid domain name.

Comment: Using `escapeshellarg` is all you need to do, and you're doing it.

Comment: Though you should be using something else as a filename component.

Comment: but if i put an domain.com | rm* it deletes files so the escapeshellarg isn't effective

Comment: @miken32 disagree that escapeshellarg is "all you need to do." One should think VERY HARD about how to avoid sticking user input directly into a shell command. I would imagine that some highly restrictive preg_match command might work, but validation would depend on the nature of the script being run. Different scripts present different risks.

Comment: @S.Imp `escapeshellarg` is completely safe, *when used correctly* (see my answer below.) I'd be very interested to see cases where it is not safe. I've used it extensively and don't want to think it's insecure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on the arguments before running them, the result is a single quoted string such as `'domain.com | rm *'`. Your problem is that you're not using this as a shell argument, but as a **portion** of a shell argument:

```
aha -b -t 'Domain test of $domain_arg'
```

This will absolutely cause the problems you're describing. Try something like this instead:

```
<?php
$domain_arg = escapeshellarg($_POST["domain"]);
$log_msg = escapeshellarg("Domain test of $_POST[domain]");
$today = date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");
$log_file = preg_replace(
    "/[^\w:\\/.-]/i",
    "_",
    "/var/www/website/results/$_POST[domain].$today.html"
);

$cmd = "/home/ubuntu/dtest/dtest.sh $domain_arg | aha -b -t $log_msg > $log_file";
$output = shell_exec($cmd);
$result = rawurlencode($output); // just guessing that's where it comes from
$today = rawurlencode($today);
header("Location: http://the.web.com/results/$result.$today.html");
```

Comment: I had to add $filename = '' . preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9]/i', '_', $_POST['domain'] ) . $today . '.html'; and set the header to the $filename and I had to add a . before the html but otherwise this works perfectly, I can no longer delete files, thank you!

Comment: I just noticed your edits, will try this version as well.

Comment: That's easy enough to fix. I hope you understand all this code before you use it in production! ;)

Comment: I wish I understood it, I got some serious reading to do.  All that preg_replace stuff has me confused.

Comment: `preg_replace` uses a regular expression to replace any unsafe characters with an underscore. It's allowing through word (`\w`) characters (0-9, a-z), colons, dashes, slashes, and dots. Anything else is gone. This may help explain: https://regex101.com/r/ocgn6p/1

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate all the time you've spent on this.  I'll read up on it and make sure I fully understand before making it live.

Answer (score -1):

You should rather use [escapeshellcmd()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) instead of escapeshellarg().